# Reinterpreting "\n" to UTF16 on Windows with MSVC

Tags: c++, file, visual-c++, character-encoding

I'm trying to write simple program that divides large txt files to smaller ones. The problem starts when it comes to UTF16 encoded files. No matter how I tried, e.g. if we have in the UTF16 LE file line ending as "0D 00 0A 00", after the division it's "0D 00 0D 0A 00" or in case of UTF16 BE "00 0D 00 0A" it turns to "00 0D 00 0D 0A". It means every time I'm saving "0D 0A" bytes no matter what. Tried different methods like below in comment. The only idea I have is to operate in binary mode, don't want to use other libraries than std. Any clues appreciated.

```
std::wifstream winfile;
std::wofstream woutfile;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::wstring line, temp;
    unsigned int limit;
    unsigned int part = 1;

    //(...)
    
    while (!winfile.eof()) {
        limit = 1000000;
        woutfile.open(save_path + std::to_string(part) + ".txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
        limit--;
        while (limit > 0 && !winfile.eof()) {
            getline(winfile, temp);
            wchar_t lf[]{ L'\n'};
            woutfile << temp << lf;   
            /*
            wchar_t lf[]{ 0x00, 0x0D, 0x00, 0x0A};
            woutfile << temp << lf;
            
            woutfile << temp << L"\n";
            woutfile << temp << std::endl;
            */
            
            limit--;
        }
        part++;
        winfile.close();
        woutfile.close();
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Open the file in binary mode and `write("\r\n", 2)` ??

Comment: Sidenote: you may be interested in [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/11082165)

Comment: `wchar_t lf[]{ L'\n'}; woutfile << temp << lf;` is a bug and undefined behaviour. `wchar_t lf[]{ 0x00, 0x0D, 0x00, 0x0A}; woutfile << temp << lf;` simply does nothing at all with `lf` (it is an empty string).

Comment: Worse still, wide-character C++ streams do *not* read or write UTF-16-encoded files.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI they should if you `imbue()` them with a UTF-16 `std::locale`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I guess so, but where can I find one?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI you'll probably have to make one yourself.

Comment: @001 works, just did it that way:
wchar_t te[]{0x00, 0x0D, 0x00, 0x0A};
woutfile.write(te, 4);
However I have to know the endianess anyway. I'm aware it must be done with std::locale like RemyLebeau proposed.

Comment: @Brian61354270 very interesting, thank you, will change the code.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI when ommiting temp so running wchar_t lf[]{ L'\n'}; woutfile << lf; I'm getting 0A only in binary mode and  0D0A in text-mode so it seems it works, and the second example doesn't work, true, it should be written with .write method and in binary mode, in text mode we will get "00 0D 00 0D 0A".

Answer (score 0):

We can see your output stream is in text mode.  It sounds like your input stream is in binary mode (or the fact that it's UTF-16 is messing up interpretation of the line endings).

With binary input, you'll read both the carriage return (CR) and line feed (LF) characters.

The default delimiter for std::getline is `'\n'`, which happens to be a line feed in virtually all implementations.  So getline treats the carriage return as just another character and divides the line at the line feed.  Thus the resulting string ends with the carriage return, which you write back out.  Then you write `'\n'` after the line, and, because the output stream is in text mode, that gets translated to CR+LF.  And thus your output strings end with CR+CR+LF.

A few ways you could handle this:

- Open the input in text mode, and, if necessary, imbue it as @RemyLebeau suggested in the comments.
- Do everything in binary mode.
- Keep everything as is but skip any trailing carriage returns as you send each line to the output stream.

Comment: I didn't use binary mode, so the read issue comes from the source file is UTF-16 encoded. I'm going to try with imbue and std::locale, otherwise binary mode and handling with endianess is the solution. Third proposition is not going to work, I will cut left 0D00 or 000D but saved CRLF with any method still will be wrong, I tried that too.